# Template parse errors: Unexpected character "EOF"

Tags: angular, indexof, ng-class

I am using `[ngClass]` based on conditions using `indexOf`. I am using `disabled` class if the result of `indexOf` is not equals to -1.  If it equals -1,  I am using `enabled` class. My code is as follows:

```
<a (click)="selectLocationId(location.pk_location_id, location.locationname, location.locationcode)"  
   [ngClass]="{
      'disabled' : disabledLocations.indexOf(location.pk_location_id)!= -1,
      'enabled' : disabledLocations.indexOf(location.pk_location_id) === -1
   }">
    {{ location.locationname + location.pk_location_id + disabledLocations[0]}}
</a>
```

With this code it is returning result  of `indexOf` as -1,  even though the value exists in array. Because I should pass value in quotes, if I put quotes, it is giving following error :

> Template parse errors: Unexpected character "EOF" (Do you have an unescaped "{" in your template? Use "{{ '{' }}") to escape it.) ("**

I tried following ways but getting same error:

1)

```
[ngClass]="{
    'disabled' : disabledLocations.indexOf(""+location.pk_location_id+"")!= -1,
    'enabled' : disabledLocations.indexOf(""+location.pk_location_id+"") === -1
}">
    {{ location.locationname }}
</a>
```

2)

```
[ngClass]="{
    'disabled' : disabledLocations.indexOf("'"+location.pk_location_id+"'")!= -1, 
    'enabled' : disabledLocations.indexOf("'"+location.pk_location_id+"'") === -1
}">
    {{ location.locationname }}
</a>
```

3)

```
[ngClass]="{
    'disabled' : disabledLocations.indexOf("location.pk_location_id")!= -1,
    'enabled' : disabledLocations.indexOf("location.pk_location_id") === -1
}">
    {{ location.locationname }}
</a>
```

4)

```
[ngClass]="{
    'disabled' : disabledLocations.indexOf('location.pk_location_id')!= -1, 
    'enabled' : disabledLocations.indexOf('location.pk_location_id') === -1
}">
    {{ location.locationname }}
</a>
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: First recommendation: refactor your code by adding a function to check if a given location is disabled or not, instead of in-lining the logic twice. That should improve readability.

Comment: Thank you.. It worked by adding function to check given location is disabled or not..